# Is it possible for a graph to have an Euler circuit and an Euler path?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Is it true that an Euler path should have two vertices of odd degree and an Euler circuit should have no vertices of odd degree? Is it therefore impossible to have a graph with both an Euler path and an Euler circuit?

Comment: Every Euler circuit is automatically an Euler path.

Comment: @Wojowu I disagree. Your comment is in contrast with the last sentence of this link: http://www.ohschools.k12.oh.us/userfiles/223/Classes/34/7_Nov25.pdf You might be confusing a Hamilton circuit with an Euler circuit.

Comment: @wojowu I have the same doubt as julia. Please, clear the doubt.

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA This all depends on how you define Euler paths and circuits. For example, following the definitions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), Eulerian circuit is just a special kind of Eulerian path.

Answer (score 1):

If a graph has an Euler circuit, i.e. a trail which uses every edge exactly once and starts and ends on the same vertex, then it is impossible to also have a trail which uses every edge exactly once and starts and ends on *different* vertices. (This is because the start and end vertices must have odd degree in the latter case, but even degree in the former case.)

Whether this means Euler circuit and Euler path are mutually exclusive or not depends on your definition of "Euler path". Some people say that an Euler path must start and end on different vertices. With that definition, a graph with an Euler circuit can't have an Euler path. Other people say that an Euler path has no restriction on start and end vertices. With that definition, a graph with an Euler circuit automatically has an Euler path (which is the same as its Euler circuit).

Answer (score 0):

No. Why? Let us start with the definitions first.

Euler Circuit: A closed trail in the graph which has all the edges in the graph.

Euler Path: An open trail in the graph which has all the edges in the graph.

Crudely, suppose we have an Euler path in the graph. Now assume we also have an Euler circuit. But the Euler path has all the edges in the graph. Now if the Euler circuit has to exist then it too must have all the edges. So such a situation is not possible.

Also, suppose we have an Euler Circuit, assume we also have an Euler path, but from analysis as above, it is not possible.

One can also verify from the conditions of Euler Path and Euler Circuit existence:

Euler Circuit: Iff all vertices have even degree (and the graph has at most 1 nontrivial component)

Euler Path: Iff exactly two vertices have odd degrees and all others have even degree (and the graph has 1 nontrivial component)

What you are thinking is however true for Hamiltonian Graphs....[Hamiltonian Cycle $\implies$ Hamiltonian Path]

Answer (score -1):

[This link](http://www.ohschools.k12.oh.us/userfiles/223/Classes/34/7_Nov25.pdf) (which you have linked in the comment to the question) states that having Euler path and circuit are mutually exclusive. The definition of Euler path in the link is, however, wrong - the definition of Euler path is that it's a *trail*, not a *path*, which visits every edge exactly once. And in the definition of trail, we allow the vertices to repeat, so, in fact, every Euler circuit is also an Euler path.

Comment: Is it not true that an Euler path has exactly two vertices of odd degree and an Euler circuit has no vertices of odd degree?

Comment: What you say for Euler circuit is true, but for Euler paths - no, because (as already mentioned) Euler path can have the same start and end vertex. For example, consider an Euler path on triangle graph which just visits every edge in order.

Comment: I found this Theorem in Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications: A connected multigraph with at least two vertices has an Euler circuit if and only if each of its vertices has an even degree and it has an Euler path if and only if it has exactly two vertices of odd degree.

Comment: In that case, Rosen might be using a different definition of Euler path than the one I use.

Comment: What is your definition? Perhaps Rosen uses the same definition as the link that I provided which you say is wrong.

Comment: Trail is a sequence $v_0v_1...v_n$ such that $v_i$ is connected to $v_{i+1}$ by an edge. We say that the trail uses an edge $vw$ if $vw=v_iv_{i+1}$ for some $i$. Euler path is a trail which uses every edge exactly once. Euler circuit is an Euler path for which $v_n=v_0$.

Comment: I think it may be helpful here to coin a term like "Euler proper path" to refer to a trail which is Eulerian and not a circuit.